# Upgrading to Thymeleaf 3 and Re-Implementing Rich HTML Email in Spring

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am migrating my project from Thymeleaf 2 to 3 and I'm having an issue with the email template resolver interfering with my web template resolver.

When we first implemented Thymeleaf we followed this document to allow for email templates and web templates and had no issues (section 4.2):

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html

During conversion to Thymeleaf 3, I worked with ONLY the one template resolver for HTML templates (using the SpringResourceTemplateResolver) and the conversion was fine.  I was able to run my application without any problems and the view templates all rendered without problems.

However, when including the email template resolver (using the ClassLoaderTemplateResolver), the following error occurs when going to any controller endpoint that returns a view:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClassLoader resource "thymeleaf/thymeleaf/login.html" does not exist
```

Which indicates it is trying to load the template from the ClassLoaderTemplateResolver and not the SpringResourceTemplateResolver.  In Thymeleaf 2 setting the Order attribute solved this problem but this doesn't appear to work in Thymeleaf 3.

I couldn't find any help in the Thymeleaf 3 documentation for having 2 Template resolvers like there was in Thymeleaf 2 docs.

Any suggestions on how to get this working or documentation that I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 3):

I have this same setup (a ClassLoaderTemplateResolver for emails and a SpringResourceTemplateResolver for html page templates).  I think you need to set this property:

```
resolver.setCheckExistence(true);
```

On whichever of your template resolvers happens first, otherwise spring will assume it exists and you will see the error your seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following setup..

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("myapp")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(webTemplateEngine());
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());       
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public TemplateEngine webTemplateEngine() {
    //this method must be defined as a bean otherwise i18n messages are not found       
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

    engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    engine.addTemplateResolver(webTemplateResolver());

    return engine;
}

private ITemplateResolver webTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");        
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public TemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(emailTemplateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}

private ITemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/email/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");        
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    return resolver;
}
}
```

And then where you need to use the email template engine, just autowire the **emailTemplateEngine** and use it

```
@Autowired
private TemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine;
```